# Getting rid of the corporations with cryptocurrency economy?

Tags: utopia

Can a zero corporations economy be managed within a fully cryptocurrency tech-economy? With no fee cryptos, can the total distribution of economic production be managed without the necessity of middle entities? Can Bakuninism come about, by the freeing of politics through trustworthy decentralization?

Comment: Basic question: who will be paying for the cryptocurrency infrastructure?

Comment: I don't suppose you could elaborate on what Bakuninism means? I'm afraid I'm not clear on what it means, either as a political or economic theory.

Comment: This should be tagged as a dystopia, not a Utopia.

Comment: Corporations exist because people group together to tackle problems to big for individuals. All crypto currency does is change the medium of exchange

Comment: Ask here: https://economics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Politics should go against the very idea of Bakuninism. Ceding anything to a political power, regardless of its formation or virtues, would be conforming to a hierarchy. No political structure will have any power, without the ability to enforce some sort of ruling upon its members, otherwise it is entirely redundant - yet that very act of enforcing places it in direct opposition to Bakunin's claim that none should have any authority over an individual.

Cryptocurrency is not going to change that, and the abolishing of corporations and middle entities will only see them replaced by new corporations and middle entities. After all, if you cannot impose your will upon another, who is going to stop them from - voluntarily - forming? There is huge advantage in pooling resources, and as long as a resource such as currency exists, those who pool the most will have power over those who do not. You could abolish currency, but that would be imposing authority on others, as if they wanted to create their own currency - voluntarily - it would be beyond anyone's right to stop them.

What do you do? Ban people from pooling resources? That goes against the principles of Bakunin. Allow them to pool resources and exert pressure on those who choose not to do so? That goes against the principles of Bakunin.

His arguments make no sense, and appear designed to appeal to those with nothing - an easy argument, as they have nothing to lose and everything to gain.

Answer (score 0):

Corporations have their purposes in the economic system -- some praiseworthy, some not. Adding a cryptocurrency to the mix changes only a few of them.

- Corporations are a structure how investors with (temporarily) surplus capital can hand that capital to entrepeneurs who use it. Those investors could be workers who manage their retirement account, for instance.
- Corporations are a structure to organize large, long-lead-time investments like building a blast furnace, developing a new new drug and getting it through the clinical trials and approval process, or high-risk, high-gain ventures like establising a *new* cryptocurrency.